# Angular.js: How do I make my radio button selected on load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

Here is the scope of my controller..
I want the first radio button to be selected on load
I've tried ng-selected="true" and ng-selected={{true}} but this does not work

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
        <div ng-class='myCtrl.themeSelected.bodyClass' class='text-div'>
            <!-- radio buttons -->
            <div class='radio-wrap'>
                <input type="radio" name="theme" ng-value="myCtrl.defaultTheme" ng-model="myCtrl.themeSelected" ng-selected="true"> Default
                <input type="radio" name="theme" ng-value="myCtrl.yellowTheme" ng-model="myCtrl.themeSelected"> Yellow
                <input type="radio" name="theme" ng-value="myCtrl.greenTheme" ng-model="myCtrl.themeSelected"> Green
                <input type="radio" name="theme" ng-value="myCtrl.redTheme" ng-model="myCtrl.themeSelected"> Red
                <input type="radio" name="theme" ng-value="myCtrl.blueTheme" ng-model="myCtrl.themeSelected"> Blue
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my controller function for the default radio button too:

```
myModule.controller('MyController', function(){
this.defaultTheme = {
    bodyClass: false,
    firstDivClass:"grayBackground",
    secondDivClass:"lightGrayBackground"
};
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `this.themeSelected` in your Controller to equal the value of the radio button you want to select. So in your case `this.themeSelected = this.defaultTheme` should pre-select the first radio button. The `ng-selected` directive shouldn't be required as it is the model that determines selected state.

[Example plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DJS4XhFHSaHejP0NeTtv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Do you read the Angular Documentation?

[Angular Documentation (input[radio])](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

You can do this in this way, and if you in this example insert a `ng-value`, than you need create an object with proper data.
But it is depending on what you need. But I think you wanted to get something like the example below

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
$scope.defaultTheme = {
    bodyClass: false,
    firstDivClass:"grayBackground",
    secondDivClass:"lightGrayBackground"
};
$scope.themeSelected = 'yellowTheme'
});
```

```css
.defaultTheme {
  background-color: white;
}
.yellowTheme {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.greenTheme {
  background-color: green;
}
.redTheme {
  background-color: red;
}
.blueTheme {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div ng-class='themeSelected' class='text-div'>
            <!-- radio buttons -->
            <div class='radio-wrap'>
                <input type="radio" name="theme" value="defaultTheme" ng-model="themeSelected"> Default
                <input type="radio" name="theme" value="yellowTheme" ng-model="themeSelected"> Yellow
                <input type="radio" name="theme" value="greenTheme" ng-model="themeSelected"> Green
                <input type="radio" name="theme" value="redTheme" ng-model="themeSelected"> Red
                <input type="radio" name="theme" value="blueTheme" ng-model="themeSelected"> Blue
            </div>
        </div>
      <p>{{themeSelected}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```